# Mail server on openshift

Tags: php, email, openshift, php-5.3

Is there a mail server cartrige on openshift? 
Or is it somehow part of php 5.3 cartrige? 
Will I be able to send email with php?

Or I have to add my own custom cartridge?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple ways to tackle this. The first is by using the steps from this blog post https://www.openshift.com/blogs/outbound-mail-ports-are-now-open-for-business-on-openshift. Another way is to use something like sengrid from our marketplace https://marketplace.openshift.com/apps/9628?restoreSearch=true#!overview.

Comment: any chance you could update your answer @niharvey? thanks